# How do I compose a list of functions?

Tags: f#

If I have a type named Person, and list of functions, for example...

```
let checks = [checkAge; checkWeight; checkHeight]
```

...where each function is of the type  (Person -> bool), and I want to do the equivalent of...

```
checkAge >> checkWeight >> checkHeight
```

...but I don't know in advance what functions are in the list, how would I do it?

I tried the following...

```
checks |> List.reduce (>>)
```

...but this gives the following error...

> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>      (Person -> bool) -> (Person -> bool) -> Person -> bool
>
> but given a
>
> (Person -> bool) -> (bool -> 'a) -> Person -> 'a
>
> The type 'Person' does not match the type 'bool'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To use the `>>` operator, the function on the right must take the result type of the one on the left as its argument. `checkAge` returns `bool`, but `checkWeight` expects `Person`. What do you want the end result to signify?

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I'm trying to combine the functions, so I can call the result in one go, instead of looping through each function one at a time. It all started as I was trying to improve the code at this F# Snippets page... http://www.fssnip.net/7h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may somehow have stumbled upon a dreaded concept. Apperently its the Voldemort (dont say his name!) of functional programming.

With no further ado lets walk right into the code:

```
type Person = 
    { Name : string
      Age : int
      Weight : int
      Height : int }

type Result = 
    | Ok of Person
    | Fail

let bind f m = 
    match m with
    | Ok p -> f p
    | _ -> Fail

let (>=>) f1 f2 = f1 >> (bind f2)

let checkAge p = 
    if p.Age > 18 then Ok(p)
    else Fail

let checkWeight p = 
    if p.Weight < 80 then Ok(p)
    else Fail

let checkHeight p = 
    if p.Height > 150 then Ok(p)
    else Fail

let checks = [ checkAge; checkWeight; checkHeight ]
let allcheckfunc = checks |> List.reduce (>=>)

let combinedChecks =
   checkAge
   >=> checkWeight
   >=> checkHeight 


let p1 = 
    { Name = "p1"
      Age = 10
      Weight = 20
      Height = 110 }

let p2 = 
    { Name = "p2"
      Age = 19
      Weight = 65
      Height = 180 }

allcheckfunc p1
combinedChecks p1

allcheckfunc p2
combinedChecks p2
```

At this point I could throw around a lot of weirdo lingo (not really true, I couldnt...), but lets just look at what I have done.

- I dropped your return value of **bool** and went for another type (**Result**) with *either* (mark that keyword!) **Ok** or **Fail**.
- Then made a helper (**bind**) to wrap and unwrapp stuff from that **Result**-type.
- And a new operator (**>=>**) to combine the stuff in reduce.

Mind that the first check-function to **Fail** will shortcut the entire chain and more or less immediately (not calling the other functions) return **Fail**. In addition you will not know where in this chain it did **Fail** or which functions ahead of any **Fail** did actually **Ok**.

There are methods to also accumulate the errors as you go along, so that you get get a feedback of type: "the checkAge returned **Fail**, but the others was [*great success*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r13riaRKGo0)

The code is mostly stolen from here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

And you may want to read about the entire website of Wlaschin and even a lot more to get into the finer and harder details if wanted.

Good luck on your journey to the upper floors of the [Ivory Tower](https://vimeo.com/113588389#t=194s). ;-)

Footnote: This is called an [Either-monad](https://vimeo.com/113707214#t=648s) usually. Its not entirely finished  and what not in the above code, but never mind... I think it will work in your case...

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! As I commented to Brunner, I was thinking of ROP when playing with that snippet, and it looks like what you're doing is related. I haven't spent enough time with your code to understand it fully, but I can see where you're going. I need to look at them both some more and decide whose to mark as the answer. I wish I could mark them both!

Comment: In all fairness I think they are quit the same. OTOH the reason for me chosing my approximation was to understand this myself. I could have used the exact same technique as Brunner, and not used the >=> operator. That is one difference I could have not used, and used same (>>) as Brunner. The other main difference in these two answers are what is returned. Mine used an OK/Fail but if looking closer at it an Some/None maps exactly to my structure, and so does the remaining code (besides the >=>). So this is the same (cue protests), though they have different names (maybe vs either).

Comment: They are pretty much the same, agreed. We are referencing the same source after all. The only protest I have is that I'm only using the forward composition operator in the simple/easy way I offered. Aside from the notation of the operator, our answers are the same, including the result. I feel like you should get marked as answer though, you have been faster than me after all. (I don't like rushing to an answer, posting just a few words, just so it was there first - but that's not what you did).

Comment: hehe. arguing about who wrote the best or who finished first ;-) you got the "simpler" one (that is a pluss!), whereas  I went all in with some (possibly more advanced) Kleisli composition. that is in fact unnecessary, as you have shown... both answers I think are good for showing different "styles".

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [Railway oriented programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) would be a good fit here.
If you choose to go this route, you basically have two options.
You can either go all in, or the quick route.

**Quick route**

You rewrite your validation functions to take a `Person option` instead of just plain `Person`.

```
let validAge (record:Record option) = 
        match record with
        | Some rec when rec.Age < 65 && rec.Age > 18 -> record
        | None -> None
```

Now you should be able to easily chain your function.

```
checks |> List.reduce (>>)
```

**All in**

Alternatively, if you are lazy and don't want to match .. with in every validation function, you can write some more code.
(samples taken from [[1](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/)])

First there's a bit of setup to do.
We'll define a special return type, so we can get meaningful error messages.

```
type Result<'TSuccess,'TFailure> = 
    | Success of 'TSuccess
    | Failure of 'TFailure
```

A bind function, to bind the validations together

```
let bind switchFunction = 
    function
    | Success s -> switchFunction s
    | Failure f -> Failure f
```

You'll have to rewrite your validation functions as well.

```
let validAge (record:Record) = 
    if record.Age < 65 && record.Age > 18 then Success input
    else Failure "Not the right age bracket"
```

Now combine with

```
checks |> List.reduce (fun acc elem -> acc >> bind elem)
```

Either way, check out the original article.
There's much more there you might be able to use :)

Edit: I just noticed that I was too slow in writing this answer once again.
Besides, I think Helge explained the concetp better than I did as well.

Comment: Maybe... But I did either. ;-)

Comment: @Brunner I had just come back to update my question, and add my answer, which was basically the same as your's and Helge's. Yes, whilst looking at the snippet, it looked to me like ROP, and I was trying to apply that principle. The code I ended up with was slightly different from yours (I didn't use a DU for example), but I think the principle was the same. Now I have to decide h=whose answer to mark as accepted! They are both excellent

Answer (score 4):

The `>>` operator is useful if you have functions that perform some transformation. For example, if you had a list of functions `Person -> Person` that turn one person into another.

In your case, it seems that you have functions `Person -> bool` and you want to build a composed function that returns true if all functions return `true`.

Using `List.reduce` you can write:

```
checks|> List.reduce (fun f g -> (fun p -> f p && g p))
```

Perhaps an easier option is to just write a function that takes a person and uses `List.forall`:

```
let checkAll checks person = checks |> List.forall (fun f -> f person)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually trying to generalise the snippet at http://www.fssnip.net/7h by writing a function that took a list of functions, combined them and ran the combined result. That snippet combines the functions manually, so it specific to the problem in question. Can I do this?